# Why coherence measure monotonicity under selective incoherent operation should be form $C\left( \rho \right) \ge \sum_n{p_nC\left( \rho _n \right)}$?

Tags: foundations, resource-theories

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0275), the authors give four postulates if a function $C$ can be taken as a coherence measure:

(C1) $C(\rho) \geqslant 0$, and $C(\rho)=0$ if and only if $\rho \in \mathcal{I}$, where $\mathcal{I}$ stands for sets of incoherent states.

(C2a) Monotonicity under incoherent operations, $C(\rho) \geqslant$ $C(\Lambda(\rho))$ if $\Lambda$ is an incoherent operation.

(C2b) Monotonicity under selective incoherent operations, $C(\rho) \geqslant \sum_{n} p_{n} C\left(\rho_{n}\right)$, where $p_{n}=\operatorname{Tr}\left(K_{n} \rho K_{n}^{\dagger}\right), \rho_{n}=$ $K_{n} \rho K_{n}^{\dagger} / p_{n}$, and $\Lambda(\rho)=\sum_{n} K_{n} \rho K_{n}^{\dagger}$ is an incoherent operation.

(C3) Nonincreasing under mixing of quantum states, i.e., convexity, $\sum_{n} p_{n} C\left(\rho_{n}\right) \geqslant C\left(\sum_{n} p_{n} \rho_{n}\right)$ for any set of states $\left\{\rho_{n}\right\}$ and any probability distribution $\left\{p_{n}\right\}$.

My question is about (C2b). Since they require $K_n \mathcal{I} K_n^\dagger\subset \mathcal{I},\forall n$, so why should (C2b) be $C\left( \rho \right) \ge \sum_n{p_nC\left( \rho _n \right)}$ instead of $C\left( \rho \right) \ge C\left( \rho _n \right) ,\forall n$?

Comment: Why not to ask the paper's authors?

Comment: Interestingly, I think that $C(\rho) \geq C(\rho_n), \forall n$ is satisfied by the $l_1$-monotone for qubits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These conditions aren't really related to coherence theory per se, they are directly inspired by the requirements that entanglement measures are typically required to satisfy, see e.g. [the old review on entanglement measures](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504163).

The reason why the stronger condition $C(\rho) \geq C(\rho_n)$ is not imposed is simply that this would rule out the vast majority of coherence/entanglement measures – coherence or entanglement, as measured by standard monotones such as the entropy, *can* actually be increased with some probability even under an incoherent/LOCC operation.

An explicit example can be found in Bennett et al.'s [Procrustean protocol for entanglement concentration](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9511030), with the relevant quote being as follows:

> [...] we note that the measurement of $k$ occasionally yields a residual state $\Psi_k$ with *more* entropy of entanglement than the original
> state $\Psi$. However, neither the measurement of $k$ nor any other local processing by one or both parties can increase the *expected* entropy of entanglement between Alice’s and Bob’s subsystems.